# Change project template in iOS development

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Ok, this one has to have been asked before but sometimes you're so lost you don't even know what to look for. I created an iOS project with a tab bar template (default basic one from Xcode). Now I don't care so much about this template and want to use a single view. I designed what I needed in the story board and modified its custom class to the controller I use.

[image] (Custom class subclass UIViewController)

Those are the only steps I have done so far. When the simulator is launched, the old template, that doesn't exist anymore in the story board, is used and is still functional. I created a new project with the template I want and I don't see anything special that I have to do in my main project to have it that way.
If someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entire sure what custom class you're setting. Obviously you can't make the class of a UIViewController a UIView. Try to include the word 'Controller' in the name of any UIViewController subclasses.

### Storyboarding a project

Do you see the storyboard at at all? If not -

Your AppDelegate.m should look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

To 'use' the storyboard,

- Hit cmd-1 to see your files in the left side bar
- Select your project (top most item)
- In the Summary section you should have 1 or 2 targets, select your target (ie: the non-test target)
- Set your storyboard under iPad/iPad Deployment Info

Alternatively under the Info tab you can set the `Main storyboard file base name` plist entry.

### Adding a View Controller

After deleting everything in the storyboard except the Tab Bar Controller Scene, ensure you're not directly setting it's view or anything special.

Drag a View Controller into the Storyboard canvas, then ctrl-drag from the centre of the Tab Bar Controller to the centre of the new controller, creating a relationship segue.

Then hit shift-cmd-k to clean and cmd-b/r to build/run :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the story board that came with the project at creation. From what I understand in your section **Adding a View Controller**, I am adding another tab but I wanted to get rid entirely of the tab bar controller and use a single view controller (one of the tabs for example). With the help of your first section, I instead created a new storyboard and set it as the project Main Storyboard. That worked, but I'm still curious how I could have achieved the same thing without creating a new storyboard.

Comment: Also, sorry for the confusion about my custom class. I just used the terminology that you see in the picture. It is really just a UIViewController. I shall also change VideoView to VideoViewController.

Comment: It's hard to tell whats happening without seeing code. I'm happy this worked out for you, IB used to cause me all kind of headaches! If this helped feel free accept the answer :)

Comment: Well, the question still holds, but that did help me solve my problem. So in my book it's all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Try delete app from device, then clean and rebuild solution